# maven jetty plugin no console logs when run forked

Tags: logging, fork, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm using maven jetty plugin to run my integration tests, for this I run jetty in forked mode (because I need to pass some jam args to the jvm)
Everything works fine but for some reasons I don't get any of my web log in the console.

When I run it non forget I get all the STDOUT, STDERR etc.. so when there is a problem I can see whats wrong, but when running forked I don't have anything so when there is a problem I have no idea where it is.

here is my pom

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.3.v20130506</version>
            <configuration>
              <contextPath>/${project.artifactId}</contextPath>
              <jvmArgs>-Denv=it -Djetty.port=8081 -javaagent:/...../jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.5.201505241946/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.5.201505241946-runtime.jar=destfile=/....../target/jacoco.exec</jvmArgs>
              <waitForChild>false</waitForChild>
              <stopKey>stopJetty</stopKey>
              <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>start-jetty</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run-forked</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <stopKey>stopJetty</stopKey>
                  <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>stop-jetty</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
```

What should I add to have all the logs in console ?